# Is it possible to pass a detail upstream in Tornado templates?

Tags: python, tornado

In Tornado, you can extend templates, which is a great feature.
Sometimes, however, I want to pass a variable to the template I'm extending.
This doesn't seem to work automatically - Is there a way to do it?

Example

```
--file.py--
render_string("Foo.html",text="Hello World")


--Foo.html--
{% extends Bar.html %}
    {%block b1 %}
    Hi Mom.
    {% end %}
{% end %}

--Bar.html--
This is a triumph.
I'm making a note here -- {{text}}
{% block b1 %}
Also, this
{% end %}
```

How can I pass the text UP the extends, so Bar.html can understand it?

Comment: You mean that context is not available in the parent template? I've just tried your example and it works: {{text}} is replaced with "Hello World".

Comment: this also works  for  me, even on windows! replied here https://groups.google.com/group/python-tornado/browse_thread/thread/e46387a70f18853c

Comment: That should work, one note though: should be `{% extends "Bar.html" %}` and `{% extends ... %}` has no `{% end %}`

Answer (score 2):

When you use `self.render()` or `self.render_string()`, tornado template engine find the first extended page and comes forward.

And, when you pass a variable to these functions, it's available from first to last templates have been extended.
So, your code is correct and haven't problem.

(And also, you should using `{% extends "Bar.html" %}` without `{% end %}` statement for it.)